# C# mysql Execute Reader with parameters Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I'm trying to create a login aspx page.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=securitytest; User=root;Password=sx;");

    cn.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from login where username=@username and password=@password", cn);

    //Add parameters to get the username and password  

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", OdbcType.VarChar);
    cmd.Parameters["@username"].Value = this.Login1.UserName;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", OdbcType.VarChar);
    cmd.Parameters["@password"].Value = this.Login1.Password;

    MySqlDataReader dr = default(MySqlDataReader);
    // Initialise a reader to read the rows from the login table.  
    // If row exists, the login is successful  

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        e.Authenticated = true;
        // Event Authenticate is true  
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySql database provider uses **?** to locate parameters in SQL. So, use **?** instead of **@** to mark your parameters in your SQL query:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from login where username=?username and password=?password", cn);

cmd.Parameters.Add("?username", OdbcType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters["?username"].Value = this.Login1.UserName;

...
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: @Mike: I am not referring to the ODBC provider. See this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html for the MySQL .Net Provider. There you will find a note saying: Prior versions of the provider used the '@' symbol to mark parameters. New version use ? instead.